# Linker not linking my own static library

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker-errors, vtk

I'm trying to create an application combining Qt 5, VTK 8.0.1 and CUDA 9.1 in Windows 10 x64, using the MSVC 14 (2015, v140) compiler.

Because of VTK, this pretty much has to be done using CMake as opposed to Visual Studio. I have built VTK 8.0.1 from source with the same compiler as above for x64 Release and Debug, and the dlls are in the PATH.

My project structure is just a single folder with everything in it (the three files below).

I decided that the simplest way of handling the different compilation needs for each library was to create a separate static library for CUDA and link it afterwards, everything else being compiled into an executable.

The problem is that doesn't matter what I do I get the error below when building

```
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol addKernel referenced in function "enum cudaError __cdecl addWithCuda(int *,int const *,int const *,unsigned int)" (?addWithCuda@@YA?AW4cudaError@@PEAHPEBH1I@Z)
```

I'm positive this has something to do with some form of C/C++ name mangling conflict, but that only gets me so far.

Please, save my christmas

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Test2 LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

# QT5
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# VTK
set(VTK_DIR "correctPath" CACHE PATH directory FORCE)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
#message(${VTK_LIBRARIES})

# CUDA
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#message(STATUS "CUDA_LIBRARIES: ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}")

# Adds all the desired files to their lists
set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    )

set(KERNELS
    kernelOnly.cu
    )

set(HEADERS
    )

set(UI
    )

set(RESOURCES
    )

# Processes Qt files
QT5_WRAP_CPP(HEADERS_MOC ${HEADERS})
QT5_WRAP_UI(UI_MOC ${UI})
QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(RESOURCES_RCC ${RESOURCES})

# Include bin directories so we can find MOC'd stuff later
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
include_directories (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

# Compile our CUDA kernel library
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61)
add_library(CudaLib STATIC ${KERNELS})
target_compile_features(CudaLib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(CudaLib PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_target_properties(CudaLib PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON)

# Compile Qt+VTK+Cpp into an executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS_MOC} ${UI_MOC} ${RESOURCES_RCC})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# Link libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    CudaLib
    Qt5::Widgets
    ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY}
    ${CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY}
    )
```

My **main.cpp**:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QVTKWidget.h>

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);
extern "C" void addKernel(int* c, const int* a, const int* b);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",
        c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]);

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size)
{
    int *dev_a = 0;
    int *dev_b = 0;
    int *dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    // replaces addKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b) syntax
    void* args[] = { &dev_c, &dev_a, &dev_b };
    cudaStatus = cudaLaunchKernel(
      (const void*)&addKernel, // pointer to kernel func.
                      dim3(1), // grid
                   dim3(size), // block
                         args  // arguments
    );

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);

    return cudaStatus;
}
```

and my **kernelOnly.cu**:

```
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Comment: Envocation `add_library(CudaLib ..)` creates a **target** `CudaLib`. In CMake *targets are not variables*, so shouldn't be dereferenced (`${CudaLib}`). Just link with a target: `target_link_libraries((${PROJECT_NAME} CudaLib ...)`.

Comment: You're right! Sadly I'm still getting the exact same error though. I've edited the question anyway

Comment: I don't think so. I'm linking `${CUDA_LIBRARIES}`, which dereferences to `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.1/lib/x64/cudart_static.lib`. The linker command is the last line of CMakeLists.txt. Additionally, I'm only getting an unresolved symbol error for my own static library. If I were failing to link the CUDA libraries I would get a bunch of them

Comment: Why is C a relevant tag? Deleted.

Comment: @Daniel Please start a comment with @<name>, so that the person gets a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
extern void addKernel(int* c, const int* a, const int* b);
```

with the `"C"`.

Comment: Actually the problem turned out to be this combined with @Tsyvarev 's comment on the question itself. Applying either change separately didn't fix the problem, but both of them together allowed me to compile!

Why is it that I don't need the "C" keyword? I thought that NVCC would compile the kernel to C, so I needed to mangle both names the same way